# Get ID of all divs with a class on a page - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to get the ID of every div with a class and send it across to another PHP file. I would assume I need all of the ID's in one variable. The ID's will be put into a mysql query where I will find data that does not equal these ID's. How can this be done?

I have tried jQuery's each function but you cannot put all of the data from that function into one variable. At least not the way i did it.

This is what i've tried.

```
$('.newsItem').each(function(){
     alert (this.id);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unable to think of a good reason why you'd want to do this. Can't you just use an ordinary HTML form?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var ids = $('.className').map(function(){
   return this.id;
}).get();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/cEbJr/2/)

Comment: You will obtain a jQuery object of strings this way. Please use `.toArray()` after such `.map` operations. And `.map` supports `this` as well.

Comment: You can also place the `.get()` at the end of the map `}).get();` to get it all done in 1 fell-swoop :)

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: That does seem neater :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the data in a array

```
 Var ids= new Array();
 $('.newsItem').each(function(){
            ids[] = $(this).attr('id');
    });
```